# Getting author's nickname as meta value

Tags: post-meta, wp-insert-post

This is code I set on function.php
I made it to have original author's nickname as custom value.

```
function data_nickname( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
$data_nickname = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'data_nickname', true);
    if(empty($data_nickname)):{
        $author_ID = $post->post_author;
        $data_nickname = get_the_author_meta('nickname',$author_ID);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'data_nickname', $data_nickname, true );}
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'data_nickname', 10, 3 );
```

Author's nickname is sometimes kept as custom value as I expected, but also nickname of modified author is kept most of time.

I only like to keep original author's nickname.  Not modified author.

How I can correct my code?

Comment: Can you please clarify distinction of "original author's nickname" and "modified author's nickname"?

Comment: Original author is person who made article first.  Modified author is person who update the article later.  Thank you

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to track the user ID? That way when the original author changes their nickname it gets updated, otherwise you could have temporary usernames and deadnames stored in post meta, and fixing it would take a lot of manual work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After review, I would expect your code to work properly: to only save the creating author's nickname, and not override it later.

Here's some code to try with slight improvements and redundancies (tested):

```php
function data_nickname( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // If the post is being updated, bail.
    if ( $update ) {
        return;
    }

    $author_ID = $post->post_author;
    $nickname  = get_the_author_meta( 'nickname', $author_ID );

    // Only set post meta if it doesn't already exist.
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'data_nickname', $nickname, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'data_nickname', 10, 3 );
```

I recommend changing the post meta key to something more clear than `data_nickname`, like `original_authors_nickname`. In five years and possibly a different developer, it will then be more clear what it's purpose is.

Comment: Thank you for your advise about name of meta key.

Comment: Thank you for your advise.  Looks like something wrong with your code.  Your code is sophisticated,  and I can not find what part I should correct.

Comment: Sorry, fixed my code.

Comment: Thank you.  It stopped showing error now, but does not produce meta key, and nickname is not saved.

Comment: I tested in a fresh WordPress install, and it worked properly. Can you please test in a fresh WordPress install and a default theme?

Comment: Thank you.  Its not fresh wordpress, but I tried your code without almost all plugins except Classic editor and Custom field template.  It does not make Meta Key yet.  My previous code screws up nick name of first author and modified author.  However it always make Meta Key at least, so I will try to brush up my code.  Thank you.

Comment: Few questions: (1) Do you have the `add_action()` line still with my changes to the function? (2) What version of WordPress are you testing with? (3) What's your process for performing tests (from creating post to checking for meta value)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146540/discussion-between-cwhiro-and-caleb).